# How to prevent overlapping textViews?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to get these textViews to appear in the corners of an imaginary square once the corresponding item in the action bar is clicked but they all keep overlapping.

I've tried both linear and relative layouts and fiddled with the constraints but with no luck.
Here's my activity_main.xml code:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Top Left"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Top Right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Bottom Left"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Bottom Right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>`
```

Here's what it looks like right now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNC9m.png)

Comment: can u share a reference that how should actually look with the reference of each button click in the appbar?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the 'gone' and height is not set correctly. the following is my Code without overlapping.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Top Left"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Top Right"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Bottom Left"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Bottom Right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```